# uninitialized constant Dragonfly::Server::Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debian, dragonfly-gem

Getting this error on server

> NameError
>
> uninitialized constant Dragonfly::Server::Serializer

Using debian+passenger+apache+Rails 3.2 + ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution a restart of server or server reset fixed the problem

If any one gets this problem make sure the engine loads while starting server or you can add require to application.rb